# How to set point selection on the chart in react-native-charts-wrapper?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, charts, react-native-charts-wrapper

I have a LineChart on my app from react-native-charts-wrapper and usually after the user taps on the chart the dates's bar appears on the chart like this:

[image]

But i need to set like just point selection, like this:

[image]

But i could not find any ways how to make it. Can somebody recommend me please how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with:

```
chart.dispatchAction({
  type: 'highlight',
  dataIndex: your_index,
});
```

More information you can find in docs.
https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#action.highlight